# Azure Webjob restarts in 0 seconds. Why?

Tags: c#, azure, error-handling, azure-webjobs

My webjob is a continuous job and is like it should in a loop so it don't stop running. I've got a small Error handling which restarts the job 5 times till it deactivate the job themselfe in code. That works fine.

But if it restarts the first time the WEBJOBS_RESTART_TIME is set to 0 or something else like in the example below. I dont know why and i know this is just a little thing but the next time it restarts it is all perfect.

Here the 0 seconds:

```
[11/30/2018 10:57:27 > 2f0a74: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -1
[11/30/2018 10:57:27 > 2f0a74: SYS INFO] Process went down, waiting for 0 seconds
[11/30/2018 10:57:27 > 2f0a74: SYS INFO] Status changed to PendingRestart
[11/30/2018 10:57:28 > 2f0a74: SYS INFO] Run script 'run.bat' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[11/30/2018 10:57:28 > 2f0a74: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
```

and this is the run after the restart:

```
[11/30/2018 10:59:07 > 2f0a74: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -1
[11/30/2018 10:59:07 > 2f0a74: SYS INFO] Process went down, waiting for 60 seconds
[11/30/2018 10:59:07 > 2f0a74: SYS INFO] Status changed to PendingRestart
[11/30/2018 11:00:09 > 2f0a74: SYS INFO] Run script 'run.bat' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[11/30/2018 11:00:09 > 2f0a74: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
```

This is how it should looks like. 60 seconds restarting time.
Why is it the first time 0?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your question is unclear - it needs to be written in English. Can you repost it in English?

Comment: No problem. Now in English

Comment: Can you post your error handling code?

Comment: Only some small exceptions wich are sending the errors to a queue and then exiting the code with "Environment.Exit(-1);"
Not the best i know but thats the first thing that occurred to me

Comment: I may find something could help you. It's about the waiting time,if the WebJob's process exited (for any good or bad reason) in less than 2 minutes since it started,for a continuous WebJob,the system is waiting for 60 seconds before it'll restart the WebJob process (hence the name "pending restart"). So i guess the process exited after 2 minutes,then it will restart immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I researched for the `WEBJOBS_RESTART_TIME` configuration setting in the [Github Kudu repo](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu). If searched for code `WEBJOBS_RESTART_TIME`, you will find the varibale [`WebJobsRestartTime`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/blob/6c645381b4974da4ab625b1de90b92bd5bd6c1fc/Kudu.Contracts/Settings/SettingsKeys.cs#L31) defined for it to used as an alias, as below.

```
public const string WebJobsRestartTime = "WEBJOBS_RESTART_TIME";
```

Then, continue to search for `WebJobsRestartTime`, there is [a code comment](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/blob/a13592e6654585d5c2ee5c6a05fa39fa812ebb84/Kudu.Core/Jobs/ContinuousJobRunner.cs#L120) explain the wait time `0` and `60` you doubt.

```
// The wait time between WebJob invocations is either WebJobsRestartTime (60 seconds by default) or if the WebJob
// Was running for at least 2 minutes there is no wait time.
```